hls stream in just_audio is not working with unity3d library
I am using just_audio to play hls-streaming audio and unity3d as a fullscreen background in my flutter Android app (unity3d project has exported as a library with unity-flutter widget). If hls stream is playing without unity or uploaded track is playing with unity - it works fine, sound is playing. When i start hls stream (set HlsAudioSource) with unity widget, unity is shown, but no sound, no errors.
I saw this in logs, when hls stream successfully played without unity:
D/CCodecConfig(27354):   string input.media-type.value = "video/avc"
D/CCodecConfig(27354):   c2::u32 output.delay.value = 12
D/CCodecConfig(27354):   string output.media-type.value = "video/raw"

Does it mean that just_audio runs videoplayer for audio hls stream ? What should i do to play hls stream with just_audio and unity3d in flutter ?
I disabled unity audio, removed all listeners, loaded different tracks for hls stream, tried to configure audio session as AudioSessionConfiguration.music(). It didnt help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
